# Splitting a String into tokens

Tags: java, arrays, split, tokenize, delimiter

I would like to split a String into tokens that are stored in an array. However i don not think I am able to use delimiters as the strings information is not separated by a specific set of characters. The information is however always separated by varying amounts of white space.

Like this:

```
0      147    530.936        1    656.336   -1.12709    656.336   -0.52921 -0.0131993  -0.882138        0       20        0        0   0.878423          0 1.4013E-045          0
```

My question is, is there a way to use the varying amounts of white space as delimiters, in order to tokenize the string?

Comment: Try using `" "` as a split separator and then iterate over all elements choosing only those that are not empty or those that do not contain white spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
String[] tokens = yourString.split("\\s+");
```

Split uses regex and in regex

- to represent any whitespace you can use `"\\s"`
- to say "one or more times" use `+`

Answer (score 0):

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");    
String[] splitArray = input.split(" ");
```